# trying to make log in page where data (email and password) is stored and read from text file, doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

the email and password successfully stores in the text file, but i am not too sure how to make it so it reads that data and if the email and password are in a list. i tried and made a function "read info" made a list there where it takes what's in the textile and puts it in the list. no matter what, the output is always "email or password wrong". I'm not too sure what to do. Thank you for the help

```
    from tkinter import*
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    import tkinter as tk
    
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('670x466')



    class Goode_brothers:


    def __init__(self, parent):

        myFrame = Frame(parent)
        myFrame.pack()


        self.load = Image.open('new-dip-project\\food.jpg')
        self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load)
        self.img = Label(parent, image = self.render)
        self.img.place(x = -26, y =0)

        self.img_login = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\button (3).png')
        self.b1 = Button(parent,image = self.img_login, command = self.read_info, bd = 0, bg = '#3b353b', activebackground = '#3b353b')
        self.b1.place(x = 275, y = 310)



        self.img_register = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\register.png')
        self.b2 = Button(parent,image = self.img_register, command = self.openNewWindow, bd = 0, bg = '#3b353b', activebackground = '#3b353b')
        self.b2.place(x = 265, y = 400)

        self.canvas = Canvas(parent, width = 400, height = 120)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('new-dip-project\\goode.png'))
        self.canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=self.img4)



        self.email = Entry(parent).place(x = 340, y = 180)
        self.password = Entry(parent).place(x = 340, y = 250)

        self.img_label = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label-image.png')
        self.name = Label(parent, image = self.img_label, text = "Email:", bg = '#3c3a3b').place(x = 197,y = 178)

        self.img_label_pass = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label_pass.png')
        self.name = Label(parent, image = self.img_label_pass, text = "Password:", bg = '#3c3a3b').place(x = 177,y = 245)




    def create_pass(self):

        self.password_length = Label(self.root2, text = '')
        self.password_length.place(x = 80, y = 140)

        self.pass_word = str(self.password2.get()) #this code is getting the users input from the password entry box

        if len(self.pass_word) >= 8: #if the characters gotten from the pasword entry is less than 8, an erorr message will appear
            self.save_info()
            self.registered = Label(self.root2, text = 'You have successfully registered, this window will now automatically close', font=("open sans", "8"))
            self.registered.place(x = 80, y = 140)
            self.root2.after(4000, self.root2.destroy)
        else:
            self.password_length.configure(text="""Your password must be atleast eight characters long. Please try again""", font=("open sans", "8"))


    def save_info(self):

         self.email_reg = str(self.email2.get())
         self.pass_word = str(self.password2.get())
         print(self.email2)
         file = open('emails.txt', 'a+')
         file.write(self.email_reg + ', ' + self.pass_word + '\n')



    def read_info(self):
        read_ep = open('emails.txt', 'r')
        email_list = []
        password_list = []

        for i in read_ep:
            a,b = i.split(', ')
            b = b.strip()
            email_list.append(a)
            password_list.append(b)
        data = dict(zip(email_list, password_list))

        if self.email and self.password in email_list and password_list:
            print('email and password exist')
        else:
            print('email or password wrong')



    def create_email(self):

        self.username_length = Label(self.root2, text = '', font = '40')
        self.username_length.place(x = 165, y = 140)

        self.email_reg = str(self.email2.get())

        if len(self.email_reg) >= 1: #if user has inputted a letter or number it will allow it to go to the next function
            self.create_pass()
            self.username_length.destroy()
        else:
            self.username_length.configure(text='Please enter your username or password', font=("open sans", "8"))
            self.username_length.after(3000, self.username_length.destroy)




    def openNewWindow(self):

        # Toplevel object which will
        # be treated as a new window
        self.root2 = Toplevel(root)

        # sets the title of the
        # Toplevel widget
        self.root2.title("New Window")

        # sets the geometry of toplevel
        self.root2.geometry("500x300")

        self.load2 = Image.open('new-dip-project\\registerscreen3.jpg')
        self.render2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load2)
        self.img2 = Label(self.root2, image = self.render2)
        self.img2.place(x = -2, y =0)

        self.img_label2 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label-image.png')
        self.name = Label(self.root2, image = self.img_label, bg = '#292929').place(x = 130,y = 102)

        self.img_label_pass2 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\label_pass.png')
        self.name = Label(self.root2, image = self.img_label_pass, bg = '#292929').place(x = 120,y = 173)

        self.email2 = Entry(self.root2)
        self.email2.place(x = 280, y = 104)

        self.password2 = Entry(self.root2)
        self.password2.place(x = 280, y = 180)

        self.img_register2 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\register.png')
        self.b3 = Button(self.root2,image = self.img_register2, command = self.create_email, bd = 0, bg = '#0d0d0d', activebackground = '#0d0d0d')
        self.b3.place(x = 180, y = 250)

        self.img_reg2 = PhotoImage(file = 'new-dip-project\\regtitle.png')
        self.name9 = Label(self.root2, image = self.img_reg2, bg = '#131313')
        self.name9.place(x = 109, y = 10)







if __name__ == "__main__":
    e = Goode_brothers(root)
    root.title('Goode brothers')
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code:

- `self.email` and `self.password` are `None` because of how they are created:

```
self.email = Entry(parent).place(x = 340, y = 180)
self.password = Entry(parent).place(x = 340, y = 250)
```

You should use:

```py
self.email = Entry(parent)
self.email.place(x = 340, y = 180)
self.password = Entry(parent)
self.password.place(x = 340, y = 250)
```

- You should use `self.email.get()` and `self.password.get()` in the if statement inside `read_info()`.  Also the expression in the if statement is incorrect.

Below is modified `read_info()`:

```py
    def read_info(self):
        email_list = []
        password_list = []

        with open("emails.txt") as read_ep:
            for i in read_ep:
                a, b = i.split(", ")
                b = b.strip()
                email_list.append(a)
                password_list.append(b)

        data = dict(zip(email_list, password_list))
        #print(data)

        email = self.email.get() # get the input email
        password = self.password.get() # get the input password

        if email in data and password == data[email]:
            print("email and password exist")
        else:
            print("email and password wrong")
```

However you can simplify `read_info()` as below:

```
    def read_info(self):
        accounts = []
        with open("emails.txt") as read_ep:
            for line in read_ep:
                accounts.append(line.strip().split(", "))
        #print(accounts)

        credential = [self.email.get(), self.password.get()]
        if credential in accounts:
            print("email and password exist")
        else:
            print("email and password wrong")
```